# JavaScript - JSON object, grouping and multiplication of values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON output called `result`:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {"id": "39036", "name": "Steve", "product": "10", "count": "5", "cost": "4"},
    {"id": "39037", "name": "Steve", "product": "11", "count": "5", "cost": "7"},
    {"id": "39038", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "5", "cost": "2"},
    {"id": "39039", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "4", "cost": "2"},
    {"id": "39040", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "1", "cost": "2"}
  ]
}
```

I need the product number, the count, the cost and the total for each product number

I.e. for above, the output would be:

```
((product 10, count 5, cost 4, total 20),
(product 11, count 5, cost 7, total 35),
(product 12, count 10, cost 2, total 20))
```

I am not sure where to begin with this, does anyone have any guidance?

Comment: You need to look for map for array in javascript

Comment: Thank you, will take a look now :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? How would you do it yourself, without a computer? Take that approach, write it down step by steps and then code it up.

Comment: I have tried doing some for loops, but it isnt working the way I wanted.. I have also tried adding each value to a list, but that didnt work. I am going to check out map arrays as per 'Boy with silver wings' suggestion..... you are right, I need to think of this off the computer first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to create one object with values and then `Object.values` to get array of objects as a result.

```js
const json = {"status" : "success", "data" : [{"id":"39036","name":"Steve","product":"10","count":"5","cost":"4"},{"id":"39037","name":"Steve","product":"11","count":"5","cost":"7"},{"id":"39038","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"5","cost":"2"},{"id":"39039","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"4","cost":"2"},{"id":"39040","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"1","cost":"2"}] }

// Take { product, count, cost} from current element in reduce callback
const result = Object.values(json.data.reduce((r, { product, count, cost}) => {
  // Check if product exists in accumulator
  // If not set its value to a new object
  if (!r[product]) r[product] = { product, count, cost, total: count * cost}
  // If it does exists update count and total values
  // +count will convert string to number
  else {
    r[product].count = +r[product].count + +count;
    r[product].total = +r[product].count * +r[product].cost
  }
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

You could also use ES6 `Map` to store data and then use `values()` method with spread syntax to get array as a result.

```js
const json = {"status" : "success", "data" : [{"id":"39036","name":"Steve","product":"10","count":"5","cost":"4"},{"id":"39037","name":"Steve","product":"11","count":"5","cost":"7"},{"id":"39038","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"5","cost":"2"},{"id":"39039","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"4","cost":"2"},{"id":"39040","name":"Steve","product":"12","count":"1","cost":"2"}] }

const map = json.data.reduce((r, {product,count,cost}) => {
  if (!r.has(product)) {
    r.set(product, { product, count, cost, total: count * cost})
  } else {
    const prod = r.get(product);
    prod.count = +prod.count + +count;
    prod.total = +prod.cost * +prod.count
  }
  return r;
}, new Map);

const result = [...map.values()]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, going to take a look now :)

Comment: IMHO this is hard to read code for beginner in JS (as the OP is). at least could have added some comments :)

Comment: We just take `{product,count,cost}` from current element in reduce using parameter destructuring, then check if product exists in accumulator, if not we add new object, if it does exist we update count and total. Also we need to convert values of `count` and `cost` to numbers because in original data they are string so that is why we use `+count`...

Comment: I know that very well, I meant for the person who asked the question. I would remove destructuring and change the way you convert strings to numbers, to make it easy for JS beginners to understand whats going on. Or just add some comments. thats it. If I ignore my readability related remarks, I will up-vote your answer now for its correctness. But if I had taken readability into account (especially when a beginner JS person has to read it) I would not have up-voted it, that's it :)

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava Thanks, I also added some comments to first example.

Comment: Quick question. My JSON output is an object, so I am getting undefined. If I do 'var data1 = $.parseJSON(data)' and then 'product1 = (data1.data[0].product)'....  I get the product value. However, if I do 'const json = data' and then do the rest of the code it is undefined. Does that mean my JSON obect is in the wrong format?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking, json is a string so after you parse it if you have object structure as you provided in the question you should be able to run this code and get same result.

Comment: You should be able to use `data1.data.reduce...` after you parsed json based on your example.

Comment: Ill give it a go now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you mention you have tried to do it with loops, it may be worth showing how that could work.

```js
var json=
'{\
  "status": "success",\
  "data": [\
    {"id": "39036", "name": "Steve", "product": "10", "count": "5", "cost": "4"},\
    {"id": "39037", "name": "Steve", "product": "11", "count": "5", "cost": "7"},\
    {"id": "39038", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "5", "cost": "2"},\
    {"id": "39039", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "4", "cost": "2"},\
    {"id": "39040", "name": "Steve", "product": "12", "count": "1", "cost": "2"}\
  ]\
}';
var data=JSON.parse(json).data;              // only the array

var result={};
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  var order=data[i];
  if(result[order.product]){                 // such product is in the result already
    result[order.product].count+=parseInt(order.count);
  }else{                                     // product is something new
    result[order.product]={
      product:order.product,
      count:parseInt(order.count),
      cost:parseInt(order.cost),
    }
  }
}

// put result in a list
var resultlist=[];
for(var product in result){
  result[product].total=result[product].cost*result[product].count;
  resultlist.push(result[product]);
}
console.log(resultlist);
```

And then comes [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you tevemadar. I will take a look now :)

Comment: @ScoutEU the "string numbers" tricked me (while it does not affect multiplication, ```count``` was concatenated), so had to edit a little. Now it works correctly. Well, I think.

Comment: Hi tevemadar. My mistake I am sure, but for some reason the array is returning {}.... so I got my array from the GET pull using 'var data = $.parseJSON(data);' and I use that data in your solution. If I enter 'product = (data.data[0].product);'  and then alert it, I do get a response, but the array is blank. any ideas :)

Comment: @ScoutEU while I do not know what you mean, on "string numbers", I referred to the constructs like ```"count": "5", "cost": "4"``` in the JSON. Here ```"5"``` and ```"4"``` are strings, but JSON actually allows numbers, that would look like ```"count": 5, "cost": 4```, without quotation marks (```"```)